# Есть кликер реализованный через localStorage для сохранения результата но при перезагрузке страницы и если кликнуть,значение в localStorage обнуляется

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    введите сюда код

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>LocalStorage</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>LocalStorage</h1>
    <p>Ваши клики <span id="result"> 0</span></p>
    <button id="myBtn">+1</button>
    <h1></h1>
    <script>
        let h1 = document.querySelector('h1')
        let result = document.querySelector('#result');
        let btn = document.querySelector('#myBtn');
        console.log(result);
        let count = 0;
        btn.addEventListener('click',function(){
            count++;
            result.textContent = count;
            localStorage.setItem('count',JSON.stringify(count))
        })
 </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При загрузке страницы вы **не считываете** значение из хранилища. Поэтому у вас следующая логика: `Загрузка страницы (count: 0) => Клики => Сохранение значения (count: 15)`.

Выполните [загрузку](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) значения при загрузке страницы

Comment: @АлександрНадежкин , вы воспользовались указанным методом? Если да, то опишите процесс \ приложите код.

Comment: Спасибо большое я разобрался